# Editor or way to print plist in a clean way without Xcode

Tags: xcode, plist

I need to share information from a plist with someone who is not technically inclined. Is there a common *free* editor that one can use to view plist info in a similar way in which it is presented in Xcode? Or is there a way to print it out?

In other words I would like to view the plist **without all the xml-like mark up and without the use of Xcode.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a "Property List Editor" app as part of OS X (or there used to be, I'm away from my machine at the moment so can't check).

Failing that, you could write one in about half an hour!

Answer (score 13):

**Command-line** options for **viewing** Plist files:

- For **viewing only**: Use `plutil -p`, which prints the content of a property-list in JSON-*like* format (the format is meant for human consumption only).

Example (append `| open -tf` to view output in a text editor):

```
plutil -p ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidebarlists.plist
```

- **Alternative**: Use `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c print`, which outputs in JavaScript-object-literal-*like* format:

Example:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c print ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.airplay.plist
```

**Caveat**:
If the plist has properties containing *binary data*, `PlistBuddy` will include it in raw form (by contrast, non-binary properties in the same file are printed properly). If XML output is desired, add option `-x`.

Note that `PlistBuddy`:

- can be used to **extract properties selectively** using `:`-separated, case-sensitive property paths; e.g., `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'print :favorites:ShowRemovable' ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidebarlists.plist`
- is also **capable of modifying Plist files** from the command line (including, with limitations, importing from previously exported-to *XML* files).

See `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -h` for details.

Answer (score 3):

The standalone "Property List Editor" is gone since Xcode 4, you can use [Pref Setter](http://www.nightproductions.net/prefsetter.html) which is free but last updated 4 years ago.

To save the contents without the xml tags see this example:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[@"~/Library/Preferences/loginwindow.plist" stringByExpandingTildeInPath]];
[[dict description] writeToURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[@"~/Desktop/loginwindow.txt" stringByExpandingTildeInPath]] atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `visual studio code` to open and edit Plist files.
Just need to install an extension in the visual studio code called `Binary Plist`:

Binary Plist

Publisher: David Nicolson

Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dnicolson.binary-plist

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to get the old [Property List Editor working on Mac OS X Lion](http://sveinbjorn.org/install_property_list_editor_app_on_mac_os_x_lion), if you don't want to use bloated XCode 4 for this.